# Scrolling UIWebView - manually setting height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Im wondering how to simply get loaded page length, and set manually its position.It's possible by moving finger through screen, but its possible to set manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, `UIWebView` has a `scrollView` property that you can access. From this, you can get the current `contentOffset`:

```
CGPoint offset = myWebView.scrollView.contentOffset;
```

And also set the scroll view's `contentOffset`, with or without animation:

```
[myWebView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 200.0) animated:YES];
```